# How to use booleanfield in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a class `Order` with `pay = models.BooleanField(default=False)`.

I would like to enable the `pay` button when somebody presses another button.

How can this be done?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example of how you can achieve that

```
def pay(request, id):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=id)
    if not order.pay:
       order.pay = True
       order.save()
```

you need to get that product either via id or slug, whatever you are using and if that had not been paid then you can pay for it.

you can add it to the urls like

```
url(r'^pay/(?P<id>\d+)/S', views.pay, name='pay')
```

Then finally in the button

```
<a href="{% url 'pay' order.id %}">Pay</a>
```

When you click this link pay function will be executed.

Comment: But what returns def pay?

Comment: it doesnot have to return anything. It just functions to mark the order paid